# unable to login to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

i have two servers
server01 with keypair-server01
server02 with keypair-server02

i have created new root volume from the snapshot of server01's root volume.
i have deattached server02's root volume and attached the created new volume.

Now server01 and server02 are up and running with same root volumes, so i have run sysprep on server02 and the server came up and i am not able to login, so how do i login to server02. will the administrator password be from server01's keypair or from server02's keypair.

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon EC2 Windows instance is first booted from a standard AWS image, code on the image will generate a random Administrator password. The password is then encrypted with the keypair associated with the instance.

Since you have copied an image and started a new EC2 instance, it is possible that the password-generation process was triggered again, with the password being encrypted by whatever keypair is associated with the new instance.

In the console, try to decrypt the password and it will tell you which keypair to use.

If, however, the server01 password was manually changed, it is possible that this password has carried-across to the new instance. Try it too!